# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.CardView

Tags: java, android

I am making a project for the first, I followed a Youtube tutorial on RecycleView but when I compile my project and launch the app on Android Studio my app crashes. I followed exactly what the video showed but it's possible that some components are not working the same way since.

This is the Output I get :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    at e.user.popcorn.RecyclerViewAdapter$MyViewHolder.<init>(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:78)
    at e.user.popcorn.RecyclerViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:33)
    at e.user.popcorn.RecyclerViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:16)
```

And this is the code 
RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
    package e.user.popcorn;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.Image;
    import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.List;

    public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext ;
    private List<movie_page> mData ;


    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<movie_page> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view ;
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_boxoffice_movie,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.tv_movie_title.setText(mData.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.img_movie_thumbnail.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getThumbnail());
        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,SelectedMovie.class);

                // passing data to the book activity
                intent.putExtra("Title",mData.get(position).getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("Description",mData.get(position).getDescription());
                intent.putExtra("Thumbnail",mData.get(position).getThumbnail());
                intent.putExtra("Categorie",mData.get(position).getCategory());
                // start the activity
                mContext.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tv_movie_title;
        ImageView img_movie_thumbnail;
        CardView cardView ;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tv_movie_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_title) ;
            img_movie_thumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_poster);
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_id);
        }
    }
}
```

And there is movie_page.java

```
package e.user.popcorn;

public class movie_page {

    private String Title;
    private String Category ;
    private String Description ;
    private int Thumbnail ;

    public movie_page() {
    }

    public movie_page(String title, String category, String description, int thumbnail) {
        Title = title;
        Category = category;
        Description = description;
        Thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }


    public String getTitle() {
        return Title;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return Category;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public int getThumbnail() {
        return Thumbnail;
    }


    public void setTitle(String title) {
        Title = title;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        Category = category;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }

    public void setThumbnail(int thumbnail) {
        Thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }
}
```

Here is Layout_boxoffice_movie.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/movie_id"
android:clickable="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/movie_poster"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@color/colorNavBackground"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/movie_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Movie Title"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorNavBackground"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry it's the first time I post, I wanted to add "Hello Everyone !" and "Thanks for your help? I hope I gave enough elements !" ! :)

Comment: share your xml code of layout_boxoffice_movie.xml

Comment: inside your layout_boxoffice_movie.xml  you are having ConstraintLayout but you are trying to find this View as a CardView , thats why this error is coming , if you share your code i can correct this error for you.

Comment: I added the layout_boxoffice_movie.xml !

Comment: ok got it , i will add an ansswer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You need to replace `ConstraintLayout` to `CardView`.

This will be your corrected code .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/movie_id"
android:clickable="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/movie_poster"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@color/colorNavBackground"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/movie_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Movie Title"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorNavBackground"/>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Hey @Daniel, if this answer helps you feel free to accept this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @Thunder ! I'm sorry if i didn't reply earlier !

Answer (score 0):

You care casting `ConstraintLayout` to `CardView`.
Change this line

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
```

with

```
android.support.v7.widget.CardView
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with below line

```
cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_id);
```

As per your layout xml file, You are using ConstraintLayout whereas You are using CardView in Your Java file. This is the real problem. You need to use CardView instead of ConstraintLayout.

Replace

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
```

With

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
```

Also take care at closing tags